# Is it possible to create NSLayoutConstraint where value is not constant but related to property?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

Constraints in iOS has base related element, constant (and also multiplier, priority and other properties, but they are not matter in this question):

```swift
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Can I relate constraint value to `superView.heightAnchor` instead constant?

Something like:

```swift
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leftAnchor, relatedTo: superView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

I want now to create `UILabel` inside rounded `UIView` where label left and right constraints must be relate to view height

My current solution is adding helper view in left side with width related to container view height:

```swift
helperView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
helperView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

But it's need additional code and views

Comment: are the left and right constraints equal? You could then center and constrain the label's width relative to the superview's width

Comment: Thank for advice but I wont to relate view left to superview height because of superview round corners. Superview width and height has not aspect ratio.